# Parse out elements from a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the result output from a natural language parser (Stanford parser).
Some of the results are as below:

```
dep(Company-1, rent-5')
conj_or(rent-5, share-10)
amod(information-12, personal-11)
prep_about(rent-5, you-14)
amod(companies-20, non-affiliated-19)
aux(provide-23, to-22)
xcomp(you-14, provide-23)
dobj(provide-23, products-24)
aux(requested-29, 've-28)
```

The result am trying to get are:

```
['dep', 'Company', 'rent']
['conj_or', 'rent', 'share']
['amod', 'information', 'personal']
...
['amod', 'companies', 'non-affiliated']
...
['aux', 'requested', "'ve"]
```

First I tried to directly get these elements out, but failed.
Then I realized regex should be the right way forward.

However, I am totally unfamiliar with regex. With some exploration, I got:

```
m = re.search('(?<=())\w+', line)
m2 =re.search('(?<=-)\d', line)
```

and stuck.

The first one can correctly get the first elements, e.g. `'dep'`, `'amod'`, `'conj_or'`, but I actually have not totally figured out why it is working...

Second line is trying to get the second elements, e.g. `'Company'`, `'rent'`, `'information'`, but I can only get the number after the word. I cannot figure out how to lookbefore rather than lookbehind...

BTW, I also cannot figure out how to deal with exceptions such as `'non-affiliated'` and `"'ve"`.

Could anyone give some hints or help. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to give an optimal answer without knowing the full range of possible outputs, however, here's a possible solution:

```
>>> [re.findall(r'[A-Za-z_\'-]+[^-\d\(\)\']', line) for line in s.split('\n')]
[['dep', 'Company', 'rent'], 
 ['conj_or', 'rent', 'share'], 
 ['amod', 'information', 'personal'], 
 ['prep_about', 'rent', 'you'], 
 ['amod', 'companies', 'non-affiliated'], 
 ['aux', 'provide', 'to'], 
 ['xcomp', 'you', 'provide'], 
 ['dobj', 'provide', 'products'], 
 ['aux', 'requested', "'ve"]]
```

It works by finding all the groups of contiguous letters (`[A-Za-z]` represent the interval between capital A and Z and small a and z) or the characters "_" and "'" in the same line.

Furthermore it enforce the rule that your matched string must not have in the last position a given list of characters (`[^...]` is the syntax to say "must not contain any of the characters (replace "..." with the list of characters)).

The character `\` escapes those characters like "(" or ")" that would otherwise be parsed by the regex engine as instructions.

Finally, `s` is the example string you gave in the question...

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you're looking for:
`([\w-]*)\(([\w-]*)-\d*, ([\w-]*)-\d*\)`

The parenthesis around `[\w-]*` are for grouping, so that you can access data as:

```
ex = r'([\w-]*)\(([\w-]*)-\d*, ([\w-]*)-\d*\)'
m = re.match(ex, line)
print(m.group(0), m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

Btw, I recommend using "Kodos" program written in Python+PyQT to learn and test regular expressions. It's my favourite tool to test regexs.

Answer (score 1):

If the results from the parser are as regular as suggested, regexes may not be necessary:

```
from pprint import pprint

source = """
dep(Company-1, rent-5')
conj_or(rent-5, share-10)
amod(information-12, personal-11)
prep_about(rent-5, you-14)
amod(companies-20, non-affiliated-19)
aux(provide-23, to-22)
xcomp(you-14, provide-23)
dobj(provide-23, products-24)
aux(requested-29, 've-28)
"""

items = []

for line in source.splitlines():
    head, sep, tail = line.partition('(')
    if head:
        item = [head]
        head, sep, tail = tail.strip('()').partition(', ')
        item.append(head.rpartition('-')[0])
        item.append(tail.rpartition('-')[0])
        items.append(item)

pprint(items)
```

Output:

```
[['dep', 'Company', 'rent'],
 ['conj_or', 'rent', 'share'],
 ['amod', 'information', 'personal'],
 ['prep_about', 'rent', 'you'],
 ['amod', 'companies', 'non-affiliated'],
 ['aux', 'provide', 'to'],
 ['xcomp', 'you', 'provide'],
 ['dobj', 'provide', 'products'],
 ['aux', 'requested', "'ve"]]
```